# select object which matches with my condition using linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list of type Person which has 3 properties Id, Name, Age

```
var per1 = new Person((1, "John", 33);
var per2 = new Person((2, "Anna", 23);

var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(per1);
persons.Add(per2);
```

using linq I want to select person which age matched with my input, for example 33.

I know how to use any but I dont know how to select object which matches with my condition.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For one match:

```
var match = persons.Single(p => your condition);
```

For many matches, use `persons.Where(condition)`. There are also many variants of picking just one person, such as `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, `Last`, `LastOrDefault`, and `SingleOrDefault`. Each has slightly different semantics depending on what exactly you want.

Comment: +1 The only problem (or advantage) with single is that it throws error when there is more/less than one object satisfying query. When you are not sure if there is only one, use `First()`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) and it will return all the matching elements collection.

```
var res = persons.Where(c=>c.AttributeName == 23);
```

If you want to ensure you have only match you can use single.

```
var res = persons.Single(c=>c.AttributeName == 23);
```

[Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.single.aspx) Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple.

```
var per1 = new Person(1, "John", 33);
var per2 = new Person(2, "Anna", 23);
var persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(per1);
persons.Add(per2);
var sirec = persons.Select(x => x.age = 33);
```

Try this and let me know

Note: If it is single value use "Single" instead of "Select"

Comment: No, YOU try it and let US know

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this.

```
if (model.Any(i => i.ParamKey == Key))
                    return model.Where(i => i.ParamKey == Key).First().ParamValue;
```

or

```
 if (model.Any(i => i.ParamKey == Key))
                        return model.Where(i => i.ParamKey == Key).First();
```